# sql how to write complicated query for noob?

Tags: sql, database

Here is my tables

```
 Student (sname, sid, gpa, level, deptno) 
 Course (cno, cname, deptno, units) 
 Dept (dname, deptno) 
 Takes (sid, cno)
```

Write a SQL query that returns the names (i.e., snames) of students who have taken 
more courses outside their department than inside their department.you can 
assume that all students in the database have taken at least one course inside their department.

I am not looking for any solutions for this question, but still welcome for any answer.
But I more hoping people can tell me how to generate the steps to write a complicated query like this..

My answer is

```
 Select S.sname
 From Student S, Course C, Dept D, Takes T
 Where T.cno=C.cno and D.deptno=C.deptno and S.sid = T.sid
 Having COUNT(S.deptno=C.deptno) > COUNT( S.deptno != C.deptno)
```

I am not sure I can use the count after HAVING in this way or not .
Thanks

Comment: Which class is this for?

Comment: Sounds like an exercise from the Stanford databases course.

Comment: i posted the solution already, so it is not for any classes.. stay calm guys

Comment: @runcode: You can give the answer query as an answer. Don't include it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt, corrected:

```
 SELECT S.sname
 FROM Student S, Course C, Dept D, Takes T
 WHERE T.cno = C.cno AND D.deptno = C.deptno AND S.sid = T.sid
 GROUP BY S.sid
 HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN S.deptno =  C.deptno THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) 
      < COUNT(CASE WHEN S.deptno <> C.deptno THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) ;
```

and converted to SQL-92 syntax:

```
 SELECT S.sname
 FROM Student S 
   JOIN Takes T   ON S.sid = T.sid
   JOIN Course C  ON T.cno = C.cno
   JOIN Dept D    ON D.deptno = C.deptno
 GROUP BY S.sid        
        , S.sname                  --- this is not needed in SQL-2003
                                   --- but still required by most DBMS     
 HAVING 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN S.deptno =  C.deptno THEN 1 END) 
      < COUNT(CASE WHEN S.deptno <> C.deptno THEN 1 END) ;

                                   --- the ELSE NULL is not needed either
                                   --- it's the implied default
```

Comment: actually I just guess COUNT can use in this way, because I never see any examples using COUNT like this, do you know any websites that have lots of SQL QUERY examples?

Comment: `COUNT(x)` counts the times that `x` is not null, so it would count both True and False. You meant to count only the True, though.

Comment: A site with SQL exercises: **[http://www.sql-ex.ru/](http://www.sql-ex.ru/)**

Answer (score 2):

I frequently work with moderately complex SQL queries despite never having taken a DB / SQL class, and find the best way to generate the query is to work one piece at a time. For example, first work on getting a list of students. Then, the number of classes they have taken inside and outside the dept and finally, compare the two values in the query and return the final result set you need.,

tl;dr: baby steps

Comment: so the way I use COUNT on the above , is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

Someone thought this is hw, but Here is the standard solution:

```
 SELECT S.sname from Student S
 WHERE (SELECT COUNT (*) 
 FROM Takes T, Course C
 WHERE S.sid = T.sid AND T.cno = C.cno AND C.deptno = S.deptno)
 < (SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM Takes T2, Course C2
 WHERE S.sid = T2.sid AND T2.cno = C2.cno AND C2.deptno != S.deptno)
```

Comment: It's correct, although I would use `JOIN` and not this 20-years old syntax.

Comment: how about my  answer included in question , is that correct?